# Unable to include foo/foo.h when using cgo to import a C function into Go

Tags: go, cgo

I'm currently practicing cgo and attempting to import my own C function into Go. My project structure consists of the following files:

`main.go /foo/foo.h /foo/foo.c`
When I include the C file, foo/foo.c, everything works as expected. However, when I try to include the corresponding header file, foo/foo.h, it fails to work. I would like to understand why this is happening.

Could someone please explain the reason behind this issue? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Include foo/foo.h header file when I write codes like the below

```
package main

/*
#include "foo/foo.h"
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := C.int(3)
    b := C.int(4)
    result := C.add(a, b)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```